# s3fs_check_service: invalid credentials - result of checking service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am using `s3fs` for mounting wrt to s3 bucket

My S3 bucket is AES256 Encrypted

The `mount` command is

```
s3fs -o dbglevel=info -o allow_other  -o use_sse=1 -o use_cache=/tmp bucketname /s3mnt
```

Doing so I don't get any error message, but the mount is not happening

```
/var/log/messages
```

has these error

```
s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3765): invalid credentials - result of checking service
```

> Apr 14 12:23:31 ip-10-245-10-14 s3fs[74691]:
>   curl.cpp:CheckBucket(2899): Check bucket failed, S3 response:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Error>
>   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
>   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
>   <RequestId>2F78B1BC9AC11266</RequestId>
>   <HostId>lonyfl8DX8DQBnOOqouDwWi7PYzwiXZl3LEWOiCjY39PlLMGnfBGWhvSRoF4UGLVCCdfkHVxxa4=</HostId>
> </Error>
> ```

Any help?

Answer (score 11):

If you're thinking that you're going nuts after having the right policies and credentials: They ARE probably correct! But is your bucket in a region other than the default `us-east-1`?

Because if it is, your credentials get lost in redirects...

> Looks like we loose auth data following redirects.
>   Adding url param like `-o url="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"` fixes the problem.

Source: 
1. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/721
2. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/721#issuecomment-382353844

Answer (score 0):

Amazon emits this error with incorrect credentials.  Make sure your `$HOME/.passwd-s3fs` or `/etc/passwd-s3fs` is correct.

Comment: yes the credentials in the password file is correct, also the same credentials am able to use it for s3 , but the s3fs is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding url=https://s3.{AWS::Region}.amazon.com in the fstab entry solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, when checking the logs using -d parameter in command to get more detailed log., found that the datetime was wrong
**The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.**

after correcting the datetime using the below command the issue is resolved.

```
timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```